# Mongoosejs can't query with findById

Tags: mongodb, express, coffeescript, mongoose, meteor

I have a meteor application saving stuff to mongodb and I have an api I wish to make and expose via REST.

```
express = require 'express'
mongoose = require 'mongoose'

app = express()

mongoose.connect process.env.MONGO_URL

Account = mongoose.model 'users',
    profile:
        available: Boolean

app.get "/accounts/meta/:account_id", (req, res) ->
    account = Account.findById req.params.account_id
    , (error, account) ->
        if account?
            res.jsonp
                account: account
        else
            res.jsonp 404,
                error: "Account not found"

app.listen 2000
```

The problem is that I can't query by the id's I see in my database. For example I have this user:

```
{
    "_id": "zcdsHuKr5dTh3xHz5",
    "createdAt": 1373188729653,
    "last_seen": 1373465529548,
    "profile": {
        ....
```

If I go to `/accounts/meta/zcdsHuKr5dTh3xHz5` it says `'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "zcdsHuKr5dTh3xHz5" at path "_id"'`. I tried in every possible way to query for my document without luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the ids of your documents an ObjectId?

Comment: It's just the string I've taken from the database itself. Don't think it's an object id. I'm still new with mongo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you need to define a schema for your model to tell Mongoose that your `_id` field is a `String` instead of the standard `ObjectId` in this collection:

```
AccountSchema = new mongoose.Schema
    _id: String
    profile:
        available: Boolean
Account = mongoose.model 'users', AccountSchema
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I went with monk given the low needs of my application but this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that your `_id` field isn't an ObjectId. The method [`findById`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) on Mongoose expects:

> id  objectid, or a value that can be casted to one

So, if your `_id` in fact isn't an ObjectId, you should query using [`findOne`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) method

```
account = Account.findOne { "_id" : req.params.account_id }
```

Comment: This fails with the same error. `{ message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "zcdsHuKr5dTh3xHz5" at path "_id"',
  name: 'CastError',
  type: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'zcdsHuKr5dTh3xHz5',
  path: '_id' }`

Comment: how is defined your Account schema?

Comment: It's basic `Account = mongoose.model('accounts');`

Comment: Exactly the same code works with monk: https://github.com/LearnBoost/monk Pretty strange

Comment: I meant  _id field, how is defined on schema?

Answer (score 1):

The currently propagated answer is not a good idea. Don't change the schema for your model to tell Mongoose that your _id field is a String. That is a bad idea in terms of validation and should be considered a hack.

Try this instead:
If you want to query for an _id in mongoose, you have to cast the _id to ObjectId

```
AccountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: ObjectID(),
    profile: {
        available: Boolean
    });
Account = mongoose.model('users', AccountSchema);
```

Mongoosejs requires you to cast the id in the query as well (I didn't find anything about this in the mongoose documentation either):

```
account = Account.findOne({ "_id" : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.account_id) });
```

Comment: In the OP's case the `_id` in the schema needs to be a string because the `_id` values in his docs are strings, not ObjectIds.  Also, you don't need to cast `_id` values to ObjectIds like you show as Mongoose does that for you.